# Attempting to get momentjs to calculate difference in times

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to setup a interval to run every morning at 0730. I am trying to use momentjs to accomplish this.

e.g:

current time - 0730 = how long to wait until it is time to run the function.

For some reason no matter how I manipulate the moment it seems to come back with some wonky math. For example it is currently 0616 in the morning and when I attempted to get this to do the math it came back with a 6hr difference not just over an hour.

```
var endOfShift = moment('0730', 'HHmm').format(),
        now = moment().utcOffset(-8).format(),
        diff = moment(now).local() - moment(endOfShift).local();        

    console.log(endOfShift); // => 2019-12-20T07:30:00+00:00
    console.log(now); // =>  2019-12-20T06:11:38-08:00
    console.log(diff); // => 24098000 milliseconds = 6.6938888889hrs
```

I have tried removing the `utcOffset` from `now` which then the out put for the time/date incorrect. I have tried adding `utcOffset` to the `endOfShift` variable. No matter how I mess with the utc it still seems to = around 6hrs when it should be about 1ish. I have tried just removing the utcOffset from everything and just let it do its thing and it still gets the math wrong.

I have also tried moment's diff method w/ similar results.

What am I missing?

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with something like this

```
const now = moment();

let targetTime = moment('07:30', 'hh:mm'); // could be in past or in future

if (targetTime.isBefore(now)) {
    targetTime = targetTime.add(1, 'day'); // add one day if waiting for tomorrows time
}

const diff = targetTime.diff(now);
console.log(diff);

const otherDiff = targetTime - now;
console.log(otherDiff);
```

The values for `diff` and `otherDiff` should be equal so it's up to you which one you prefer.